Dune book with very obscure character from 20th century?
In one of the Dune books, was there ever a very minor mention of a person who wound up (through some unknown mechanism) in the Dune universe from our time (20th century)?  This wouldn't have been in the first Dune book, but in a sequel/prequel.

Certainly not in any of Frank's books, though I haven't read all of Brian's.

It sounds like it might have been a "Dune" book, rather than a Dune book. :-P

I'm tempted to post a straight "no, there isn't".

Might you be referring to some or other aspect of other memory? Various historical characters are given a voice and referenced through the Napoleons, John Bartlet, Agamemnon, the house of Ἀτρεύς etc.. Of course, Leto liked Bach's music too.

No, this was more of a 'lost in time' sort of person; a person of no historical significance.  It might have been in a book with 'no-ships'.

Norma Cenva (Oracle of Time, Holtzman Drive) was from later than 20th century, so presumably not her...?

Pretty sure there isn't, and I've read all of Frank's books, plus all of Brian and Kevin's too. Norma Cenva comes from the time of the Butlerian Jihad. There are mentions of people and events from history, and the painting that Darwi Odrade (I think it was) has in Heretics/Chapterhouse.

Paul and Leto II both reference historical figures, including many from the 20th century, but we never meet anyone that ancient in the flesh.

Might you be conflating Dune into Asimov's Galactic Empire? Pebble in the Sky has a 20th century person lost in time, and the mood of the story might make one thik of Dune.

Dune and Pebble in the Sky have no similarity - at all.

The painting owned by Darwi Odrade is by Van Gogh, not my notion of an historically insignificant figure. @Ash according to the OP the "20th C. figure lost in time" is mentioned, not encountered.

I wonder if you might be interpreting the characters Daniel and Marty as 20th century time travelers in the Dune universe. These characters struck me, when I read Chapterhouse: Dune, as observers of the events of the last one or two Frank Herbert books as though through a dreamlike vision: their description always landed with me like a older suburban or rural couple working in their residential garden (with 20th century overtones).
